Angular form field referencing in dynamic formgroups
I'm currently evaluating Angular as a means to implement a complex, dynamic (showon) form.  I would like to use 'grouping' where appropriate, but I'm still unclear how the referencing works as, depending on the product, groups may be nested in other groups and some dynamic fields may need to reference something nested unknown levels inside another group.
Essentially, the products are customizable and other options can vary based on prior options picked. Examples: Custom imprinting is only available on some materials. Some imprint positions sometimes have to be ommitted if another option is in that location. (e.g. a front-center cover cutout prevents front-center imprinting). Some imprint colors need to be ommitted for some materials. (e.g. black imprint on black material is not visible). Some entire options won't appear unless another option is selected. (e.g. additional material and color only show when a 2 material upgrade is chosen)
If I'm grouping like:
Product:
  -> Cover Options:
    -> Upgrades
       -> cut-outs for images
       -> two material upgrade
       -> three material upgrade
       -> non-imprintable upgrade
           -> etchable upgrade
    -> (Materials - only on non-upgraded or two/three material above)
       -> color
       
       (-> second material / color options - only on 2&3 mat upgrades)
       (-> accent material / color - only on 3 mat upgrade)
       
    -> (Imprint y/n - only on imprintable materials/upgrades)
      -> (imprint options - some field options restricted based on sub-upgrade selections or material colors)
    -> (Etching y/n - only on some non-imprintable upgrades)
      -> (etching options)

parenthesis are option groups that might not show based on previous selections.  So if I have Nested groups for Cover Options->Cover Upgrades->* and Over Options->Materials->dependent materials, how do you access these in angular from something nested down in Imprint options?
This is a limited set example. I don't have to have to include dependent duplicate option groups under each dependent case, but wasn't clear on how you search through a nested-group form set up to find thing. (mind you, depths and branches might vary on other products so I'm looking for something akin to DOM node searching to 'find' a given option another option might depend upon)
I know how to do the basic testing of these, but whats the most efficient way to find the other field values? Bind them to a known data format? Or is there an in-form-group way to 'find' them no matter how deep they are nested or perhaps even no matter 'where' they are nested?
Most of the 'examples' I see are using what amounts to shallow, absolute referencing of specific 'known' data structures.  Ultimately I want to create a 'product builder' so the data/nesting structure is up to the user creating a new product.
SW
